# Top and bottom half of screen are shifted to top half of screen while installing Ubuntu 12.04 via USB stick

Tags: system-installation, display-resolution, screen

When installing Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB stick, as soon as the installer runs, an error message appears and I can only see the upper half of the screen.

Based on the way the pointer disappears at the bottom appearing directly at the top of the display, it looks as if both halves of the screen are positioned in the upper half of the screen.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I tried to change the resolution at the display options with the limited screen that I could see, but this didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the Graphics card...

When you get to the menu after booting from USB,
There will be some options to edit the entries like "press 'e' to edit...".

After doing so find the words: `quiet splash` and type `nomodeset` before quiet splash.
So it becomes: `nomodeset quiet splash`

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> (or <kbd>F10</kbd>) to boot.
Hope that works...

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description of the problem, I can assume that the problem can be related to graphic card or it's driver. So, you can try to use nomodeset option from boot options as shown in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) link.